# how to database in arabic & urdu language fetch in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am implementing a Multi Language Supporting Application in which, first Screen in language selection English,Arabic and Urdu.

Language in local database created on Sqlite Field in Azakar_name, Azakar_arabic and Azakar_urdu, I have selected the english then Azakar_name Field Display and Arabic Select then Azakar_arabic_Field Display.

but problem in Arabic And Urdu Language Display Error:

> "azkar_arabic" = "\U0645\U0633\U062c\U062f
>   \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0630\U0643\U0627\U0631"